# firebase is not giving me the permission i need

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, firebase-security

[image: the warning im reciving]

```js
  firebase.database().ref('meetups').push(meetup)
            .then((data)=> {
                console.log(data)
                commit('createMeetup', meetup)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
```

I was doing a project made by academind called "project with vuejs vuetify and firebase"

my firebase database rules are:
[image]

Comment: Can you share your rules from the Firebase console?

Comment: i just posted on the question, tks btw

Comment: im new in firebase so i dont know if were that rules that you wanted

Comment: The problem is that you are denying every request with those rules. You can take a look at [Firebase RTDB rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) so you can edit them to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access The Firebase Realtime Database is controlled by server-side security rules The error message you're getting matches the security rules that you shared. Those rules say that no ordinary user can read or write any data from or to the database.

The simplest change that you can make to allow the operation you shared is to allow anyone to write a node under `/meetups`. The rules for that would be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    read: false,
    "meetups": {
      "$meetupId": {
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With these rules, anyone can write a new node under `/meetups`. But nobody can read any data, nor can anyone write anywhere else (including writing to `/meetups` itself).

The exact rules you need depend purely on the app that you're building. I recommend:

- Reading the [documentation for Firebase Database security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).
- Watching this [video about security rules in Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUBnlbjZFAI)
- Reading my answer here: [Firebase email saying my realtime database has insecure rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392059/firebase-email-saying-my-realtime-database-has-insecure-rules)