# Warning from firebase realtime database regarding rules, but I have updated

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
{
  "rules": {
    
    ".read": "true",  
      ".write": "true",
  }
}
```

Even after updating my rules with this, still I'm receiving warnings that I should update my firebase realtime database and also, I have also received that if I have modified rules in last 24 hours, those changes are not accounted for, what do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

The rules in your question allow anyone in the world to read and write whatever they want in your database. If they know the URL of your database, they can steal and/or wipe all of your data with a single call.

That's what the Firebase email is warning you about. I highly recommend studying it carefully, and then following up with:

- the Firebase documentation on its [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules)
- the [Realtime Database specific documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) for the rules, including the video in there
- [Firebase email saying my realtime database has insecure rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392059/firebase-email-saying-my-realtime-database-has-insecure-rules)

Comment: So if I Edit my rules  more securely, then firebase wont send me any warnings?

Comment: //'code' {
  "rules": {
    
    "user":{
      
      ".read": "true",  
      ".write": "root.child('admin').hasChild(auth.uid)",
    }
     
  }
}   this is how I have updated the rules. Is it ok now sir? @Fank van Puffelen

Comment: Yes, if you write more secure rules you shoud stop getting that warning and that rule should be enough if you need public read access to your DB.