# Firebase authentication with email and password not working with new google-services

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

My Unity/Android app is not allowing email and password registration, but it works with other google-services.json files (the code is the same as I've used in several games, so it shouldn't be the issue, and it works with other google-services.json files).

The error returned is: OperationNotAllowed.

As I mentioned, it works in other games, and I've set up Firebase the same way as other apps. I've also enabled email/password in the Sign-In menu.

[sign-in-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAO8s.png)

And in the database, everything is allowed:

[database-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtEyz.png)

{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
}
}

I have already tried creating other Firebase projects, and in all of them, none of the google-services work. However, when I use the google-services from one of my older Firebase projects, they work.
The Firebase SDK is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enabled Authentication in your current Firebase Project. Go to the console, select the project you are currently working on, if Authentication is not currently set up, enable it, configure it and **redownload your google-services.json**.

Compare the newly downloaded one to the previous and check if some new fields were added. Additionally check if the config that works has those same extra fields.

It may be that only the project that has the working google-services.json has Authentication set up; It needs to be enabled per project and the most up-to-date config file should be used. The [instructions for using Auth on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin#before_you_begin) have a bit more detail about this.

Related: Consider [changing your Realtime Database security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51393449/18173626) to lock them down further as the defaults you have listed are relatively insecure.